# batch script to echo variable content into text file

Tags: batch-file

So I have a variable "Var" I want to echo its content into a text file, now this doesn't work

```
set Var=1
echo %Var%>text.txt
```

if you add space like this, it'll work :

```
set Var=1
echo %Var% >text.txt
```

How can I echo just "1" without a space after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because it takes `1` for the out [stream which is under 1](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for the batch files.
Try this:

```
(echo(%Var%)>text.txt
```

or

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set var=1
echo !var!>text.txt
```

or

```
@echo off

set var=1

1>test.txt  echo %var%
```